# How to capture a flag in Teeworlds?

Tags: teeworlds

I have been playing Teeworlds for a while but still can't understand the capture the flag logic. What exactly should I do to capture the flag in Teeworlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the flag, you need to run into the *bottom* of the flag with your tee, and take it to your base, but your own flag needs to be at your base.  You have to run into the bottom of the flag though, they did that because what with all the chaining and fast movement it was only fair.  Hope this helps, comment if anything is unclear, keep playing teeworlds!